# Populating states DDL using country DDL in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I am populating states DDL using the country DDL

```
public static IEnumerable bindcountry()
{
    var countries = from c in getdata().Descendants(("country"))
                    orderby (string)c.Element("name")
                    select (string)c.Element("name");
    return countries;
}

public List<string> GetStatesByCountry(string CountryName)
{

    var query = from user in getdata().Descendants("country")
                where user.Element("name").Value == CountryName
                from t in user.Descendants("text")
                select t.Value;
    return query.ToList();
}

foreach (var VARIABLE in ProfileMasterDAL.bindcountry())
{
    if (VARIABLE.ToString().Contains(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text))
    {
        var query = from row in ProfileMasterDAL.bindcountry()
                    where row.(ProfileMasterDAL.GetStatesByCountrys(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text))
                    select row;

        DropDownList2.DataSource = query;
        DropDownList2.DataBind();
    }
}
```

The problem is I am unable to define WHERE clause and equals here I am getting an error:

> Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type
>   'System.Collections.IEnumerable'.  'Where' not found.  Consider
>   explicitly specifying the type of the range variable 'row'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that you are trying to populate a DropDownList with the names of the States for a given Country and it looks like that logic is in your `foreach` loop. It also looks like your `foreach` loop is doing a lot of unnecessary work.

It's iterating through all the Country names when it really only needs to find one of those country names.  It also then iterates again through the country names looking for the states.

You should be able to throw out that entire `foreach` loop and instead use this:

```
var query = ProfileMasterDAL.GetStatesByCountry(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text);
DropDownList2.DataSource = query;   
DropDownList2.DataBind();
```

Your `GetStatesByCountry` method returns just the states that belong to the passed in Country name, so you should just be able to call that, get the names of just those States, and then assign them to your `DropDownList`.

Comment: but before this code i am coding like   DropDownList1.SelectedValue = Session["country"].ToString();   and the country DDL values is not changing to another country how can i change it?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
public static IEnumerable bindcountry()     
{           
var countries = from c in getdata().Descendants(("country")) orderby (string)c.Element("name") select (string)c.Element("name");

return countries ;       
}
```

to

```
public static IList<string> bindcountry()     
{           
var countries = from c in getdata().Descendants(("country")) orderby (string)c.Element("name") select (string)c.Element("name");        

return countries.ToList() ;       
}
```

Comment: When i do like this at query it says Enumeration yields no results and the states DDL is empty.

Comment: Does it throw you an exception when you change the query?

Comment: When i debug the code i am getting like Enumeration yields no results at the query.

Comment: Then it means that you don't have any data in the DB or that you haven't set it up correctly.

Comment: I have the values in a XML and when i check at profilemaster.bincountry() and ProfileMasterDAL.GetStatesByCountrys(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text) i am getting the values but i dnt know why query yields no results